# Tensorflow 2.9 - Slow operations image.resize(), argmax() and numpy()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorrt

I am doing predictions with a TensorRT model in GPU that outputs a segmentation mask for the given image. I apply argmax and image.resize to have every pixel class value in the original image size.

While the other TF functions take less than 3ms each, image.resize() needs up to 50ms to do the work. This blows up my project considering that I have to have the mask under 20ms approx.

```
prd_tf = model(img_tf)

# Segmentation output mask
msk_tf = tf.argmax(prd_tf['conv2d_19'], axis=-1) # < 3ms                            
msk_tf = tf.reshape(msk_tf, (512, 512, 1)) # < 3ms                                     
msk_tf = tf.image.resize(msk_tf, (img_height, img_width), method='nearest') # > 40 ms
msk_tf = tf.reshape(msk_tf, (img_height, img_width)) # < 3ms
```

That seems a little odd to me because image.resize() is taking 15x more time than the other Tensorflow functions

## What I have tried

### DataType to int16

I thought that maybe the resize is taking so much time due to the type it is handeling. As I only need uint8 (up to 256 classes) I tried to output the argmax in int16 type (I have also tried int32). The surprise is that now argmax takes > 40 ms and the other ones, including resize, take < 3ms.

```
# Segmentation output mask
msk_tf = tf.argmax(prd_tf['conv2d_19'], axis=-1, output_type='int16') # > 40ms                            
msk_tf = tf.reshape(msk_tf, (512, 512, 1)) # < 3ms                                     
msk_tf = tf.image.resize(msk_tf, (img_height, img_width), method='nearest') # < 3 ms
msk_tf = tf.reshape(msk_tf, (img_height, img_width)) # < 3ms
```

### Numpy workaround

After experimenting the situation above, I figured something strange is happening in Tensorflow and I decided to do the analog functions in numpy and forget about this issue. BUT, turns out that if you do .numpy() the operation takes also > 40 ms and the other ones < 3ms

```
msk_np = prd_tf['conv2d_19'].numpy() # > 40 ms
# ...
```

## My questions

- Why this is happening?
- Which solution do I have to have the output mask under 20 ms?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: those are one-run time or have averaged over many trials? maybe your cpu/gpu was just clogged at that moment

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia no, those are averaged over many trials